# Selenium: Wait for empy element (span) to contain any text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

So, I have an issue regarding a slow loading data that throws my Selenium off.

The page itself finish loading but I then have data show up at a random interval (scripts are running which can take X amount of time) in a designated span. It may display as empty or with the string "n/a".

Note: chart-data-window-item-value class is NOT unique and I must use XPATH to find the right div/span.

I'm looking to wait for a span to fill up with a random decimal and then continue.

Empty span:

```
<div class="chart-data-window-item-value"><span style="color:"></span></div>
```

or

```
<div class="chart-data-window-item-value"><span style="color:">n/a</span></div>
```

Once data has loaded:

```
<div class="chart-data-window-item-value"><span style="color:rgba(255, 127, 0, 1)">73.26000000</span></div>
```

I have tried various methods, last being:

```
# wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[10]/div[2]/span'), r"(?<=\()[0-9]*)"))
```

No luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `time.sleep()`? This works for me. Also sets `pageLoadStrategy` to `none` which will bypass some defense mechanism.

Comment: Please post a link to the page... there *has* to be a better locator than that. That is going to be extremely brittle. It starts at the `html` tag and goes through way too many levels along with using lots of indices. Any one of those is asking for trouble but you've got all 3 combined.

Comment: @jeffc I cant, the indicator used us proprieteray, however, its added to a chart like this, https://www.tradingview.com/chart/LW1VvtHB/ where the "datatab" on the left indicate how it looks like. Also, yes, the locator is garbage, but it's WIP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom expected condition to check the span has valid text instead of regex.

```
class element_has_some_valid_text(object):
  def __init__(self, locator):
    self.locator = locator
    self.css_class = css_class

  def __call__(self, driver):
    element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)   
    if element.text and element.text != "n/a":
        return element
    else:
        return False

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
element = wait.until(element_has_some_valid_text((By.XPATH, 'your xpath goes here'))
```

Also your xpath to long, please check whether it is unique. Add more html details to question to help you for short and clear xpath.

Comment: This won't work because he said that sometimes before it's loaded it contains "n/a".

Comment: Yes. Added that n/a  condition to custom wait :)

Comment: css_class is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. If you look at [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element) for `text_to_be_present_in_element`, you will see off to the right a [source] link. Click that and take a look at the source to see how it works. The condition checked is `self.text in element_text` which is a contains. With this info, you should be able to just look for a `.` in the element text which would indicate that your number has appeared.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[10]/div[2]/span'), '.'))
```

Your code was using a regex (I think)... that method doesn't accept regex and probably just processed it as an actual string.